# How to lock git push origin master behind sudo

Tags: git, github

I'd like to make it possible to prevent myself from accidentally pushing to master, as such I think the best thing to do would be locking `git push origin master` unless I have sudo permissions.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I'd still like to push to other branches without having to enter a password to GitHub.

Comment: Instead of sudo, maybe you could have a pre-push hook that checks if the branch is the master branch and need you to confirm before pushing.

Comment: Is this hook stored on server, so that everyone using the repo needs to confirm?

Comment: @TylerHarden no this is a client hook. That is why using 2 git repos is easiers. All the contributor to the second repo won't be able to push to the first.

Answer (score 0):

An another approach would be to have two GitHub repos, on two different accounts.

- one represents the master branch
- the other is a fork of the first, and represents any branch you want

Working on the second repo (with the second account) means you *cannot* push to the first.